# Google Drive doesn't appear on my Finder

Tags: macbook-pro, google, google-apps

I can see Dropbox but I can't find Google Drive on my Finder. If I want to sync a file to GDrive, I have to open the folder GDrive by click on the symbol of Gdrive. It's very inconvenient.

I'm wondering if there is a way to display GDrive on the Finder, just like where Dropbox is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that by "if there is a way to display GDrive on the Finder, just like where Dropbox is" you mean to display it in a sidebar, right?

To do that, just go to your home folder (/Users/[username]) and ... drag and drop Google Drive folder to sidebar.

Comment: That's what I want to do. Thank you Marek. Sorry for not able to vote up your answer. I'm a newbie :(

Answer (score 4):

It's most definitely in your home folder(username), that's where ***Google Drive*** folder is found just like ***Dropbox.***

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question, and just figured this out for my older macbook.  My User wasn't on the Favorites bar, either.

[image]

A) On the Finder menu, click "Finder", then click "Preferences"

[image]

B) Click the "Sidebar" icon, then choose the box next to your User

[image]

Answer (score 1):

OSX 10.10 Yosemite
After downloading and dragging to Applications I went to the applications folder and ran the install, the Google Drive location appeared in my finder at the end of the installation

Answer (score 1):

Go to your application folder. click on google drive to open it. then in the top menu from the finder click FILE>ADD TO SIDEBAR.